# Styling a "choose file" button

Tags: html, css

Is there any way I can kind of "mask" the "choose file" button behind the 'Upload A Photo' button? So that when you click the nice looking button it brings up the file browser?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/rUdf2/4/

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/rUdf2/6/

Essential part:

1. Add an ID (or whatever "mark" that works) to the `<input type="file">` element;
2. Add `display:none` to `div#upload-wrap` so that the `<input type="file">` is invisible;
3. Add `onclick="document.getElementById('upload-field').click();"` to the "upload a photo" button.

Answer (score 0):

As Passerby sayed you have to hide the `<input type="file">` element and with jquery (or javascript) add this

```
$('#share-bottom button').click(function () {
        $('#upload-wrap-button').click();
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XnXeh/